# Обратное геокодирование не определяет ближайший адре

Tags: yandex-geocoding-api

Пытаюсь освоить обратное геокодирование. Обратил внимание, если указать координаты точно здания - то выдаст и номер дома и улицу.

Если задать точку рядом со зданием, например тротуар, то выдаст только район.

вот пример запроса:

```
https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?apikey=<ТУТ_БЫЛ_МОЙ_КЛЮЧ>&geocode=49.096984635821386,55.821039447296975&format=json&results=2&ll=49.096984635821386,55.821039447296975&spn=3,2&rspn=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужен дом, добавьте в запрос `&kind=house` и уберите `&ll=49.096984635821386,55.821039447296975&spn=3,2&rspn=1` — при поиске по координатам они только мешают работе сервиса.